# How to Represent Functional Boolean

Tags: c#, functional-programming, data-types, boolean

.NET Boolean type usually makes `if` `else` pair all over the code.

Functional Boolean should be more like `Either` type. Ideally represented as `Either<Unit, Unit>`.

However, my issues with Either type are the following:

1. `Either<Unit, Unit>` verbose, ideally it should not be generic type
2. It is not communicating clearly that `EitherLeft` is `false` and `EitherRight` is `true`

There is [a library](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) that solves this, here are some examples

```csharp
TrueOrFalse IsWeekend()
{
    var dow = DateTimeOffset.Now.DayOfWeek;

    if (dow == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        return new TrueOrFalse.True();
    }

    return new TrueOrFalse.False();
}

YesNoOrMaybe CanPurchaseAlcohol(int age)
{
    if (age < 16)
    {
        return new YesNoOrMaybe.No();
    }

    if (age >= 21)
    {
        return new YesNoOrMaybe.Yes();
    }

    return new YesNoOrMaybe.Maybe();
}
```

However, I have issues with this one as well

1. I do not want to have 2 similar libraries in my projects solving similar problems.
2. `new TrueOrFalse.True()` seems to me as wasteful, allocating objects every time which in essence `Unit.Default`. I would Prefer something like `TrueOrFalse.True.Default`
3. [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) mainly uses structs, where [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) uses classes. That is why I would like to stick with [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext)

I was thinking to create a specialized type, let's call it Binate (still working on the name) which will be similar to `Either<Negative, Positive>`, where `Positive` and `Negative` are specialized `Unit` types.

However, that will mean copying and renaming types from [language-ext](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext)

---

My question is, how have you solved this problem in your projects? Which approach would you recommend?

P.S. originally posted [here](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/discussions/1173)

Comment: Seems to me you get everything you want if you replace your `if`/`else` constructs with the ternary operator. It is not a coincidence that the ternary operator in functional languages is spelt `if ... else`.

Comment: Honest question, and I don't mean to be demeaning, but would you really rather have `TrueOrFalse` and `return new TrueOrFalse.True()` all over your code base instead of `bool` and `return true`?

Comment: Let me cite [from this article con Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/it-came-from-planet-architecture/) *"Here's the key distinction between an architecture astronaut and a practical developer: when you're in the trenches proving your ideas by implementing them in real applications. The kind used by actual users."* .   IMHO what you presented us is nothing I would ever use in a real world project to replace simple, standard, straightforward conditionals.

Comment: @Alexander I meant it to be used not everywhere, but in case where we will have split logic like in feature flags. For instance
`ShowAdvancedStatisticsFeature.Match(t => ShowAdvancedStatistics(), f => ShowSimpleStatistics())`
Just to make it more explicit that both cases should be regression tested for example.

Answer (score 10):

The "*functional version*" of booleans is the [*Church Encoding of Booleans in the λ-calculus*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_Booleans).

In λ-calculus, the only abstraction mechanism that exists, are (anonymous) functions. So, naturally, *every* data type and data structure has to be implemented with functions, and this includes booleans. In the Church Encoding, booleans are implemented as a pair of functions of two parameters, where one function evaluates the first argument and throws away the second and the other function evaluates the second argument and throws away the first:

[Note: I am going to use Scala for the sample code, since some of the concepts easily get lost between the syntactic noise of C#. Also, all of the following is runnable code, I have put in links to the online Scala evaluator for every code snippet.]

```scala
trait Buul:
  def apply[T](a: T, b: T): T

object Tru extends Buul:
  override def apply[T](a: T, b: T) = a

object Fls extends Buul:
  override def apply[T](a: T, b: T) = b
```

So, basically `Tru` is a function (the `apply` method means it can be called like a function) which takes two arguments, `a` and `b`, returns `a` and ignores `b`, and `Fls` is the reverse.

Now, how the heck is this a boolean? Well, let's play around with it. I'll add a an implicit conversion which will automatically convert Scala's built-in booleans to my newly-defined booleans:

```scala
object BuulExtension:
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def boolean2Buul(b: => Boolean): Buul = if b then Tru else Fls
```

Now, I can call something like:

```scala
(2 < 3)("2 is less than 3", "3 is greater than 2")
//=> "2 is less than 3"

(4 < 3)("4 is less than 3", "4 is greater than 3")
//=> "4 is greater than 3"
```

[[See it in action here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/pEArmvrxTlCnwtw8IhWuhw).]

So, if the conditional `(2 < 3)` is `Tru`, then the first argument will be returned, if it is `Fls`, then the second argument will be returned. In other words: the two boolean functions `Tru` and `Fls` act like a conditional expression!

By the way, do you notice something else? Our two "data values" also behave like functions. Does that remind you of something? They are *objects* (in the "OOP" sense of the word). And in fact, this is also exactly how booleans are implemented in object-oriented languages like Smalltalk. It might be surprising to some people that an encoding for λ-calculus from the 1920s turns out to be object-oriented, but it is actually really not surprising at all: the only construct in λ-calculus is the function, so the only abstraction mechanism is using functions. Since OOP is all about behavioral abstraction, it should not be surprising that λ-calculus is kind-of the first OOP language. But I digress.

There is, however, a small problem with our implementation:

```scala
(2 < 3)(println("2 is less than 3"), println("3 is greater than 2"))
// 2 is less than 3
// 3 is greater than 2

(4 < 3)(println("4 is less than 3"), println("4 is greater than 3"))
// 4 is less than 3
// 4 is greater than 3
```

λ-calculus is *lazy*, meaning, it only evaluates function arguments that are actually used. Scala (and C#, like most mainstream languages) is *eager*, meaning function arguments are always evaluated before being passed into the function. So, our "`if`" always evaluates both the "then"-branch and the "else"-branch – not good! Note: it still only *returns* the *one* result, but it *evaluates* both, so if the branches have side-effects (such as printing to the terminal), then the side-effects of *both* branches will be executed.

However, there is a simple trick to delay the evaluation of something: wrap it in a function. If we make the two parameters functions, then the side-effects will only be executed when we call the function:

```scala
trait Buul:
  def apply[T](a: => T)(b: => T): T

object Tru extends Buul:
  override def apply[T](a: => T)(b: => T) = a

object Fls extends Buul:
  override def apply[T](a: => T)(b: => T) = b

(2 < 3) { println("2 is less than 3") } { println("3 is greater than 2") }
// 2 is less than 3

(4 < 3) { println("4 is less than 3") } { println("4 is greater than 3") }
// 4 is greater than 3
```

[[See it in action here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZULxcme3RvixaqofGMMpBw).]

[Here we are using some Scala niceties: in Scala, a method can have more than one parameter list, which is nice because if you have a parameter list with exactly one parameter which is a function, you can then use curly braces to call the method. This makes it look indistinguishable from built-in control structures.]

Nice! We have a working `if`!

What about the operators, though? Let's think about how we can implement those:

```scala
trait Buul:
  def apply[T](a: => T)(b: => T): T
  def ∧(other: => Buul): Buul
  def ∨(other: => Buul): Buul
  def unary_! : Buul

object Tru extends Buul:
  override def apply[T](a: => T)(b: => T) = a
  override def ∧(other: => Buul) = other
  override def ∨(other: => Buul) = this
  override def unary_! = Fls

object Fls extends Buul:
  override def apply[T](a: => T)(b: => T) = b
  override def ∧(other: => Buul) = this
  override def ∨(other: => Buul) = other
  override def unary_! = Tru

(Tru ∧ Tru) { println("t") } { println("f") } // t
(Tru ∧ Fls) { println("t") } { println("f") } // f
(Fls ∧ Tru) { println("t") } { println("f") } // f
(Fls ∧ Fls) { println("t") } { println("f") } // f

(Tru ∨ Tru) { println("t") } { println("f") } // t
(Tru ∨ Fls) { println("t") } { println("f") } // t
(Fls ∨ Tru) { println("t") } { println("f") } // t
(Fls ∨ Fls) { println("t") } { println("f") } // f

(!Tru) { println("t") } { println("f") } // f
(!Fls) { println("t") } { println("f") } // t
```

[[See it in action here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/XrwSKghdRRy9Iu3Blf5B8A).]

I hope the logic is clear. For example, for `Tru`, the AND-operator is: `Tru &&& Tru == Tru`, `Tru &&& Fls == Fls`, so really, `Tru &&& something` is just `something`. So, we can define the result of the `&&&` operator for `Tru` just to be "the other operand". And the same or similar logic applies to the other 3 binary operators, as well as for the unary NOT-operator.

Here is the full implementation, with some more general types and more type-safety, again [fully runnable example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/E1btWAxgSmG21LNhCuKOzQ):

```scala
sealed abstract trait Buul:
  def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: => U)(els: => V): T
  infix def ∧(other: => Buul): Buul
  infix def ∨(other: => Buul): Buul
  def unary_! : Buul

case object Tru extends Buul:
  override def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: => U)(els: => V): U = thn
  override infix def ∧(other: => Buul) = other
  override infix def ∨(other: => Buul): this.type = this
  override def unary_! = Fls

case object Fls extends Buul:
  override def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: => U)(els: => V): V = els
  override infix def ∧(other: => Buul): this.type = this
  override infix def ∨(other: => Buul) = other
  override def unary_! = Tru
```

In C#, the whole thing would be a bit more verbose, and look a little bit like this:

```csharp
interface Buul {
    public T Apply<T>(Func<T> thn, Func<T> els);
    public void Apply(Action thn, Action els);
    public Buul And(Buul other);
    public Buul Or(Buul other);
    public Buul Not { get; }
    
    public static Tru T = new Tru();
    public static Fls F = new Fls();
    public static Buul FromBool(bool b) => b ? T : F;

    public record class Tru: Buul {
        internal Tru() {}
        public T Apply<T>(Func<T> thn, Func<T> els) => thn();
        public void Apply(Action thn, Action els) => thn();
        public Buul And(Buul other) => other;
        public Buul Or(Buul other) => this;
        public Buul Not { get => F; }
    }

    public record class Fls: Buul {
        internal Fls() {}
        public T Apply<T>(Func<T> thn, Func<T> els) => els();
        public void Apply(Action thn, Action els) => els();
        public Buul And(Buul other) => this;
        public Buul Or(Buul other) => other;
        public Buul Not { get => T; }
    }
}
```

This is how you would use it:

```csharp
Buul.FromBool(2 < 3).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("2 is less than 3"), () => Console.WriteLine("2 is less than 3"));
// 2 is less than 3
Buul.FromBool(4 < 3).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("4 is less than 3"), () => Console.WriteLine("4 is greater than 3"));
// 4 is greater than 3

Buul.T.And(Buul.T).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // t
Buul.T.And(Buul.F).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // f
Buul.F.And(Buul.T).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // f
Buul.F.And(Buul.F).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // f

Buul.T.Or(Buul.T).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // t
Buul.T.Or(Buul.F).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // t
Buul.F.Or(Buul.T).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // t
Buul.F.Or(Buul.F).Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // f

Buul.T.Not.Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // f
Buul.F.Not.Apply(() => Console.WriteLine("t"), () => Console.WriteLine("f")); // t
```

[[See it in action here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iw7kVg).]

So, there you have it: a functional / object-oriented implementation of booleans in C#.

But, here's the problem: it is absolutely useless. Why? Because there are tens of thousands of existing methods which return `bool`s and there are tens of thousands of existing methods which take `bool`s as arguments.

You can add implicit conversions from `bool` to `Buul` and vice-versa, you can add your own helpers, wrappers, extension methods, etc., but there will *always* be an impedance mismatch.

> My question is, how have you solved this problem in your projects?

I don't consider it a problem.

> Which approach would you recommend?

None. There is no problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I see this sort of question a lot more than I expected, where someone feels a boolean isn't "functional" enough, but really the boolean type itself is fine. As Jörg pointed out, the standard operations on booleans are basically syntactic sugar for much more fundamental operations.

From a more practical point of view, it seems what you're missing isn't a more "functional" boolean type, but more *operations* on the existing type that more clearly express your intent. Functional programmers create higher order functions all the time for similar purposes.

One example that comes to mind is [Either.cond](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/util/Either$.html#cond-fffff37b). It lets you write something like `Either.cond(boolean, rightValue, leftValue)` instead of `if boolean then Right(rightValue) else Left(leftValue)`. It clarifies your intent that you are creating an `Either` based on a boolean, ensures you handle both conditions, and reduces some boilerplate.

So I would encourage you to think more about the functions you want and create those (perhaps with extension methods), rather than trying to invent a new type.

Comment: What is wrong with the ternary `(boolean ? rightValue : leftValue)`, which is the standard idiomatic way of a functional conditional expression all kind of languages rooted on the C syntax?

Comment: Nothing, if that's all you want to do, but if you are doing more with each part, in a common pattern, you might want to factor that out into a function. The main benefit of an `Either` isn't the representation, it's all the useful functions that are defined for it.